# Split slash in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I need split text in Oracle SQL,

Input and output shown in picture.
In first secture I have orginal data in one column ( in picture A column).
In second secture which I need to return back(output).

my query is :

```sql
select val,
      CASE 
            when substr(val, 1, instr(val, '/') - 1)   is null then   val 
            ELSE substr(val, 1, instr(val, '/') - 1) 
      end as "LEVEL1",
      substr(VAL, 
             instr(val, '/',1)+1, 
             instr(val, '/',1,2)-instr(val, '/',1)-1) "LEVEL2",
      substr(VAL, instr(val, '/') ) "aparat3"
from rmtd1.split_row;
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Always remember to show your working out

Comment: [Here's](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+split+string+by+delimiter) an [example](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/split-comma-separated-values-into-rows-in-oracle-database) using [`regexp_substr(input,'[^/]',1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm)

Comment: @DaveyBoy my query
select val,
      CASE when substr(val, 1, instr(val, '/') - 1)   is null then   val ELSE substr(val, 1, instr(val, '/') - 1) end as "LEVEL1",

     substr(VAL, instr(val, '/',1)+1, instr(val, '/',1,2)-instr(val, '/',1)-1)   "level2" from dual

Comment: @Zegarek I searched it, it is not easy as you think

Comment: @NurlanGanbarzada I'm not sure what you think I thought but it is the first result for that phrase and [it works](https://dbfiddle.uk/9a8OIEnE) as long as you replace `,` with your desired `/`. If you find a problem with using the example, feel free to update the question describing what the problem is.

Comment: dear @Zegarek INPUT and OUTPUT shown in picture, please be careful.

Comment: I have one column with namely A as in picture I need split that with '/ '(slash) to multiple column (A.B,C,D )

Comment: What is the problem with your current code (other than you're selecting from dual, not you real table; and dual doesn't have a val column)? [It basically works](https://dbfiddle.uk/xPoX1hHt). Please edit your question to show your sample data, expected results, current query and current results/error as formatted text (not images), and explain what issue you are having.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string by delimiter in Oracle with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869830/split-string-by-delimiter-in-oracle-with-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need more than [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html)

```sql
select 
  val, 
  regexp_substr (val,'(^|/)([^/]*)',1, 1, null, 2) as level1,
  regexp_substr (val,'(^|/)([^/]*)',1, 2, null, 2) as level2,
  regexp_substr (val,'(^|/)([^/]*)',1, 3, null, 2) as level3,
  regexp_substr (val,'(^|/)([^/]*)',1, 4, null, 2) as level4
from your_table;
```

1. `(^|/)` finds the beginning or a `/`
2. `([^/]*)` catches everything that comes after each hit from `(^|/)`
3. 3rd parameter (`1`) tells it where to start in your input
4. 4th parameter (`1`-`4`) selects which of your hits is returned
5. 5th parameter lets you [tweak](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_INSTR.html#GUID-D21B53A1-83E2-4722-9BBB-638470715DD6) how matches are determined
6. last parameter selects the hit from your second subexpression `([^/]*)` in point 2. above

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gruclh0Z)

Answer (score 0):

Another method for arguments sake.

```
WITH tbl(val) AS (
SELECT 'aaa/bbbas/cc/dd' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'xzz/cca' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'dddddddd/xsssda/asasasasq' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'ddtrr5fd5sdwe' FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(val, '(.*?)(/|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS col_1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(val, '(.*?)(/|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) AS col_2,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(val, '(.*?)(/|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) AS col_3,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(val, '(.*?)(/|$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1) AS col_4
FROM tbl;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vN6FFRfh)